python-telegram-bot not processing updates from other people in a group
While reading updates from python-telegram-bot, it seems the bot reads updates from everyone (privacy already checked, privacy mode is disabled), but only process updates that come from the user that triggered /start.
The bot follows this logic.
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    user_id       = update.effective_user.id
    chat_id       = update.effective_chat.id
    if(user_id != chat_id):
        try:
            await update.effective_chat.send_message("(Welcome message) Beginning registry… I need everyone to send me a message to register you!")
            HANDLER.insert_chat(chat_id, members) # DB Related stuff
        except IntegrityError as i:
            await update.effective_chat.send_message("(Chat_already_registered) Looks like you triggered /start in a registered chat! Going back to read updates.")
        return REGISTRATION

# For debugging purposes
async def register(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    await update.effective_chat.send_message(f"DEBUG: I've read your update")
    return REGISTRATION

def main() -> None:
    convStart = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points = [CommandHandler("start", start)],
        states = {MAIN_LOOP: [MessageHandler(None, update_chat)],
                  REGISTRATION: [MessageHandler(None, register)]},
        fallbacks = [CommandHandler("stop", error)],
        allow_reentry = True
    )
    application = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).concurrent_updates(True).pool_timeout(350).connection_pool_size(700).build()
    application.add_handler(convStart)
    application.add_error_handler(error)
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates = Update.ALL_TYPES, poll_interval = 0.1)

The logs throw this:
# User processed
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:04:47,567 - telegram.ext.ExtBot - DEBUG - (Update(message=Message(channel_chat_created=False, chat=Chat(id=FOOBAR, is_forum=True, title='Test01', type=<ChatType.SUPERGROUP>), date=datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 18, 13, 4, 47, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), delete_chat_photo=False, from_user=User(first_name='FOOBAR', id=FOOBAR, is_bot=False, language_code='es', last_name='FOOBAR', username='FOOBAR'), group_chat_created=False, message_id=573, supergroup_chat_created=False, text=''), update_id=463104382),)
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:04:47,568 - telegram.ext.ExtBot - DEBUG - Exiting: get_updates
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:04:47,568 - telegram.ext.Application - DEBUG - Processing update Update(message=Message(channel_chat_created=False, chat=Chat(id=-FOOBAR, is_forum=True, title='Test01', type=<ChatType.SUPERGROUP>), date=datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 18, 13, 4, 47, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), delete_chat_photo=False, from_user=User(first_name='FOOBAR', id=FOOBAR, is_bot=False, language_code='es', last_name='FOOBAR', username='FOOBAR'), group_chat_created=False, message_id=573, supergroup_chat_created=False, text=''), update_id=463104382)
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:04:47,569 - telegram.ext.ConversationHandler - DEBUG - Selecting conversation (GROUP_ID, USER_ID) with state 1
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:04:47,569 - telegram.ext.ExtBot - DEBUG - Entering: send_message
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:04:47,571 - httpcore.connection - DEBUG - close.started
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:04:47,572 - httpcore.connection - DEBUG - close.complete

# User not processed
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:05:00,514 - telegram.ext.ExtBot - DEBUG - (Update(message=Message(channel_chat_created=False, chat=Chat(id=FOOBAR, is_forum=True, title='Test01', type=<ChatType.SUPERGROUP>), date=datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 18, 13, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), delete_chat_photo=False, from_user=User(first_name='FOOBAR', id=FOOBAR, is_bot=False, language_code='de', last_name='FOOBAR', username='FOOBAR'), group_chat_created=False, message_id=575, supergroup_chat_created=False, text=''), update_id=463104383),)
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:05:00,515 - telegram.ext.ExtBot - DEBUG - Exiting: get_updates
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:05:00,515 - telegram.ext.Application - DEBUG - Processing update Update(message=Message(channel_chat_created=False, chat=Chat(id=FOOBAR, is_forum=True, title='Test01', type=<ChatType.SUPERGROUP>), date=datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 18, 13, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), delete_chat_photo=False, from_user=User(first_name='FOOBAR', id=FOOBAR, is_bot=False, language_code='de', last_name='FOOBAR', username='FOOBAR'), group_chat_created=False, message_id=575, supergroup_chat_created=False, text=''), update_id=463104383)
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:05:00,516 - telegram.ext.ConversationHandler - DEBUG - Selecting conversation (CHAT_ID, USER_ID) with state None
MAIN APP - 2024-04-18 07:05:00,617 - telegram.ext.ExtBot - DEBUG - Entering: get_updates

I'm suspecting it may be the language (mine is in spanish, his is in german)?… Also, worth notice the main difference is that the states are 1 and None respectively.

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-do-the-per_-settings-in-conversationhandler-do
